# Why did the price of a comic book convince Susan that Josh was telling the truth?

Tags: plot-explanation, big

> BACKGROUND CHARACTER: How much would the unit cost?
> SUSAN: Well, our initial figure is around...around $7.00, with a retail cost of around $18.95.
> PAUL: You expect a kid to pay $19.00 for a comic book?
> SUSAN: I think a kid... Would you excuse me?

In the scene with the above transcript, Susan is convinced that Josh is telling the truth about

> his age.

Why? Did I miss a major scene?

Comment: I don’t think it’s the comic price, it’s the discussion of how kids think that triggers her thoughts about Josh which leads to her changing her mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was, according to the script and [novelisation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Big-B-Hiller/dp/0345354885), simply the moment at which she finally put two and two together and came up with four. She already had the proof in her hands (including the "*your wish is granted*" card and Josh's outright confession) but it wasn't until that point that she actually believed him, realising that the various events she'd encountered all made sense now.

> “How much would the unit cost to make?” Mac asked the critical question.
> “Well, our initial figure is around seven dollars,” she said, still glancing at the door. She turned back to MacMillan. “Around seven dollars with a retail price of, say, eighteen ninety-five.”
> “Do you think a kid is going to pop for nineteen bucks for a comic book?' Paul scoffed from his end of the table.
> **“I think a kid . . She trailed off, a shocked expression on her face. Why had a kid burst into Josh’s office that morning? Why was Josh letting her run the presentation?**
> Where the hell had he gone right in the middle of
> it?
>
> <sub><sup>[Big: Official Movie Novelisation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Big-B-Hiller/dp/0345354885)</sup></sub>

Comment: This seems to confirm it's her internal thought process and not the comic book pricing that leads to the realization.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Yes. She's already puzzled by a great many things at this point. I think this is just supposed to be the *'crystallising moment'* when she simply accepts at face-value the things that Josh told her.